# Calculate sum each value separated by a comma

Tags: vb.net

how should I use this correct code to calculate the sum of values by comma gender:

Textbox1.Text =

```
1,2
7,1
8,1,3
2,71
20
8,1
27,1
```

Total numbers:  14
Sum of numbers: 153.0

Example Two:

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
```

Total numbers:  6
Sum of numbers: 21.0

Code:

```
 Dim total As Single = 0.00
 For Each line As String In TextBox1.Text.Split(vbLf)
    If IsNumeric(line) Then
       total += CSng(line)
    End If
 Next
 TextBox2.Text = total
```

Comment: First things first, don't split the `Text`. The `TextBox` has a `Lines` property. This is an example of why I keep banging on about reading the documentation. One perk of doing so is that you pick up information that you may not even have been looking for. People who read the documentation for the `TextBox` class may see that `Lines` property and, even if they don;t need to use it now, will then know about it if they do need it later.

Comment: Secondly, you obviously have data that contains multiple numbers separated by commas, yet I see nothing in that code that could possibly handle that. You seem not to have even attempted that part. As you should ALWAYS do, the first thing you should be doing is NOT writing code. Treat it as a manual exercise and work out the steps required to get the desired result. Once you have detailed steps that work every time, that's the algorithm that you need to implement in code. If you don't know what your code has to do before writing it, you really haven't done all you can.

Comment: Have a look at the Split function on the [.NET String Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @jazakari, they already know about the `Split` function because they are using it (although incorrectly) to split the `Text`, which is not required, while not using it to split the individual lines, which is required.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your input (TextBox1) contains mixed contents like:

```
1, 2

3, 4
5, 6
A, B, C, D
...
Some other text...
a3z
A, 3, D
```

To extract the numeric values and sum them by a single line using Linq:

```vb
TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Lines.
    SelectMany(Function(x) x.Split(","c)).
    Where(Function(x) Single.TryParse(x, Nothing)).
    Sum(Function(x) Single.Parse(x)).ToString("f1")
```

If you have to use `For Each..Loop`, then you can use the [Array.FindAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.findall?view=netframework-4.8) method as follows:

```vb
Dim total = 0F

For Each line In TextBox1.Lines
    total += Array.FindAll(line.Split(","c),
                            Function(x) Single.TryParse(x, Nothing)).
                            Sum(Function(x) Single.Parse(x))
Next

TextBox2.Text = total.ToString("f1")
```

Comment: it works very well and properly, that's exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Explanations and comments inline.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    'It seems all the numbers you are using are Integers
    'so just use Integer as the type
    Dim total As Integer
    'You can get an array of the lines in the textbox as follows
    Dim lines = TextBox1.Lines
    'BTW .Split(vbCrLf) won't work .Split expects a Char or Char array
    For Each line As String In lines
        'If IsNumeric(line) Then
        'This will never return true becaus of the comma
        'IsNumeric is an old vb6 function replaced by .TryParse methods
        'First you need to split your line into however many numbers you have
        Dim numbers = line.Split(","c) 'the small c tells the compiler that this String is really a Char
        For Each num In numbers
            total += CInt(num) 'remember num is still a String so must be changed to a number to do arithmetic
        Next
    Next
    TextBox2.Text = total.ToString
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I love one liners a lot.
Try this:

```
TextBox1.Text = String.Join(",", TextBox1.Lines).Split(","c).Select(Function(s) CInt(s.Trim())).Sum().ToString()
```